# $\{\prod_{i=1}^{r} H_{i}\} \bigcap H_{r+1} = \{e\} \Rightarrow H_{i}\bigcap H_{j} = \{e\} \; \forall i\neq j$?

Tags: group-theory, direct-product

I am studying Internal Direct Products in Group Theory.

> $\mbox{Let}$ $G$ be a group and  $H_{i}\lhd G\;  \forall i=1,2\ldots
> > n$
>
> Suppose $\{\prod_{i=1}^{r} H_{i}\} \bigcap H_{r+1} = \{e\} \; \forall
> > r=1,2\ldots    (n-1)$ then prove that $H_{i}\bigcap H_{j} = \{e\} \;
> \forall i\neq j$
>
> But **converse** is true only if $n=2$

First of all, I am really not sure about the validity of these statements since I am reading from a not-so-standard material.

I tried to prove $(\Rightarrow)$ like this$:$

Let $a\in H_{i}\bigcap H_{j},\; \; a\neq e, \; \; f.s. \;  i\neq j$

$\Rightarrow a\in H_{i}$ and $a \in H_{j}$

WLOG, assume $i < j $

Clearly, $a \in \prod_{i=1}^{j-1}H_{i}$ since we can write $a=e.e\ldots  a.e.\dots e$
$\Rightarrow \{\prod_{i=1}^{j-1}H_{i} \} \bigcap H_{j} \neq \{e\} \; \; \mbox{contradiction}$

Converse is obviously true for $n=2$ but how can I show it is not true for $n>2$?

Comment: Have you tried to prove this theorem... solo? :)

Comment: @MonstrousMoonshiner I've proved one side of it in the description itself

Comment: Yes, I was just making a silly joke...

Comment: @MonstrousMoonshiner ohh, my bad :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counter example :
Group $Z_3\times Z_3$ under +

$N_1=${$(0,0),(1,0),(2,0)$}

$N_2=${$(0,0)(0,1)(0,2)$}

$N_3=${$(0,0)(1,1)(2,2)$}

$N_1N_2\cap N_3=${$(0,0),(1,1)(2,2)$}